Check if git finished cloning after terminal crashed
I was cloning a large repository when the terminal crashed. Is there a way for me to tell if the clone managed to finish (including submodules)? I'd prefer to not have to wait for the lengthy clone again.

a basic check; go to target directory, run git status

Issue a git pull to force it to continue, without cloning from scratch, if previously interrupted.
